# How to map a String as a dict in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a string in python:-

```
Stock Price,apple:105.2,Goog:101,TSLA:200,Time:2021:10:10 10:15:22
```

How do I map it to:-

```
{'apple':105.2  ,'Goog':101,'TSLA':200,Time:2021:10:10 10:15:22 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will throw an error.** A dictionary value can't have multiple numerical values separated by a colon (as shown with the `Time` key). I think you meant the following:

```
dictionary = {'apple': 105.2, 'Goog': 101, 'TSLA': 200, 'Time': '2021:10:10:23'}
```

You can use the following code:

```
dictionary = {}

string = 'Stock Price,apple:105.2,Goog:101,TSLA:200,Time:2021:10:10:23'

# Split the string by commas and store the items in a list
enter code herestring_items = string.split(",") # ['Stock Price', 'apple:105.2', 'Goog:101', 'TSLA:200', 'Time:2021:10:10:23']
     
# Remove the first item (i.e., "Stock Price")
string_items.pop(0)

for item in string_item:
    dictionary[item.split(":", 1)[0]] = item.split(":", 1)[1]
```

**Note:** This will still keep the numbers as a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes:

```
str = "Stock Price,apple:105.2,Goog:101,TSLA:200,Time:2021:10:10:23"

s = str.split(',')[1:]
stocks = {}
for tickr in s:
    new_dict = tickr.split(':')
    stocks[new_dict[0]] = new_dict[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string on commas, skip the first part. Then use these strings in a dictionary constructor by splitting them on the first colon:

```
s = 'Stock Price,apple:105.2,Goog:101,TSLA:200,Time:2021:10:10:23'
d = dict(kv.split(':',1) for kv in s.split(',')[1:])

print(d)
{'apple': '105.2', 'Goog': '101', 'TSLA': '200', 'Time': '2021:10:10:23'}
```

*You will have to do an extra step to convert the 'time' value to an actual datetime object.*